# Can't install IPA made with Distribution OTA in Xcode 5

Tags: xcode, ios7, ota

after upgrade in Xcode 5, I have no problem to build (and Archive OTA version)
But provisionning management have change in Xcode, I have renew my provisionning, refresh all in XCode and use a "Distribution" Build for Archiving (I have check signing identity, and certificat, all is done).
I try some hours to build an OTA version but not work.
The standard Distribution build work well, just the OTA notwork.

Comment: I have find the problem, need to edit the pbxproj file into xcodeproj "folder" and clean all entry about certificate and provisionning !